# Dynamically changing form action not working for MailChimp

Tags: javascript, jquery, mailchimp

I am using a checkbox to change the form action on a MailChimp-form dynamically. When the DOM is loaded, the form action URL is something like this:

```
https://X.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=X&amp;id=X&EBIRD=XYZ
```

When I submit the form, the EBIRD-value of XYZ is pushed to MailChimp. Now, when I check the checkbox, I can see from the DOM and my console that the new form action is this:

```
https://X.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=X&amp;id=X&EBIRD=NEW-VALUE
```

Why is it then, that submitting the form still pushes XYZ and not NEW-VALUE? I have been in touch with MailChimp technical support. They said that when choosing "View Source" on the page, the old value was still there. But isn't that just because that is how the page is loaded in the first place?

Relevant HTML:

```
<form action="https://X.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=X&amp;id=X&EBIRD=XYZ" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
```

Relevant jQuery:

```
    var formActionYes = "https://X.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=X&amp;id=X&EBIRD=NEW-VALUE";
    var formActionNo = "https://X.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=X&amp;id=X&EBIRD=NEW-VALUE-2";

    $('#cu-ebird').change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").prop('action',formActionYes);
            console.log($("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").prop('action'));
        } else {
            $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").prop('action',formActionNo);
            console.log($("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").prop('action'));
        }               
    });
```

The console logs what I want. The DOM shows what I want. MailChimp recieves the old value.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by not trying to change the form action at all. Just remove the merge field from the form action. Instead, you need to add a hidden input field to your form:

```
<input id="ebird" type="hidden" name="EBIRD" value="">
```

Then you change the value of this using the script:

```
$("#ebird").attr('value','NEW-VALUE');
```

Voila, everything shows up in MailChimp as it should.

Comment: Sounds like MailChimp requires this to be a POST parameter rather than a GET parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use HTML entities like `&amp;` in JavaScript strings. That's only processed in HTML code, not when properties are assigned in JavaScript.

```
var formActionYes = "https://X.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=X&id=X&EBIRD=NEW-VALUE";
var formActionNo = "https://X.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=X&id=X&EBIRD=NEW-VALUE-2";
```

Although I'm not sure why this would impact the `EBIRD` parameter. It should cause the `id` parameter to be renamed to `amp;id`.

Another thing you could try is using `.attr()` rather than `.prop()`.

Comment: I thought that was on purpose from MailChimp, but I guess not. Changing it to just & made no difference. Using .attr() also made no difference. It's almost as if MailChimp takes the form action on page load and not on submit? Or is it so that the form action is bound to the submit button on form load and needs to be unbound and rebound in some way?

Comment: I have also now tried to have a hidden input field with a value that gets passed. It works if I don't change the value dynamically. If I change it, nothing goes through. Not even the original value. Maybe it has something to do with the event listener on the submit button? I'll look into it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Hidden input field works. Just a typo in my code.